# How to change column attributes on Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In the picture, it shows my problem: I need to display the values of a column from a table in apex. Currently all the values are being displayed as a text field. But, I need to display only a few as text fields and others as just a display value without allowing someone to edit it. I've been looking into it, but I'm stuck.. There is a conditional display area, but not sure if that is where I need to go for the solution. That section seems to just limit what values get displayed not change the display format based on the values, but that latter is what i need. Thanks if you know or can point me in the right direction!

[image]

Comment: you could add: disabled="true" to the element attributes

Comment: Is the requirement that **all** the values in a certain column cannot be edited, or that they can be edited on **some** rows but not on others?

Comment: Ill try it Typo, and Tony: That they can be edited on some rows but not others, the latter was just a change of the display as value.

Comment: Ok, the disabled="true" is the functionality I am looking for, but I only want that on certain columns. Is that a possible feature?

Comment: certain columns or rows? If columns - change "display as" attribute of this columns. If rows - add new column in your select statement with value, depending on your condition (enable or disable edidting current row). Value must be "disabled="true"" when disabled editing certain row, and null if enabled. Then add value of this row in "Element attributes" of certain columns that you need to disable/enable.

Comment: From what I can tell you need to implement a solution similar to this for conditions on each row https://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2007/12/01/conditional-column-formatting-in-apex/

Comment: Nogotnu: I mispoke, it is the rows.  Both: Your solutions seem similar and it looks exactly like what i want, ill try it out later. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have another column(IS_EDITABLE) that is set to disabled="true" or NULL based on my conditions and those are being set. I printed out the column value of #IS_EDITABLE# in the UPDATE_ column I am using, and the value is being set correctly. But for some reason the element attributes doesn't recognize the #IS_EDITABLE# column value or something because when i just put disabled="true" in the element attributes spot, the row is not editable. But when using the #IS_EDITABLE# that is being set to disabled="true", the row is still editable. Any ideas on how that is fixable? @NoGotnu

Comment: Look to html-code of your element, when you use #IS_EDITABLE#. May be something goes wrong, and may be it wrapped in some other element. Another way is to set value of IS_EDITABLE column to some class (for example "not_editable"). And then use it in "Element CSS Classes" attribute of a column. Don't forget to describe this class in header of page.

Answer (score 0):

In the Item properties , go to advanced section
in custom attributes mention readonly=’readonly’-- this will make that item as display only.